# Characterization of étale locally constant sheaves over a normal scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, etale-cohomology

I have a question about the verification of remark 1.2 in James Milne's book [Étale Cohomology](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9781400883981/html?lang=de#contents) stated on page 156:

Assume $X$ be a normal & connected scheme with generic
point $g: \eta \to X$.
Then the claim is that an étale sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ with finite stalks is *locally constant*
(i.e., there exists an étale cover $(U_i \to X)_i$ such that each $\mathcal{F} \rvert_{U_i}$ is a constant sheaf, cf. §1, Prop. 1.1) if and only if the *unit map* $\mathcal{F} \to g_*g^*\mathcal{F}$ is an isomorphism and the Galois action by $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{k(\eta)}/ k(\eta))$ on the stalk $\mathcal{F}_{\overline{\eta}}$ factors through the étale fundamental group
$\pi_1(X, \overline{\eta})$.

**Question:** How to see that this holds?

Few remarks:

- $\pi_1(X, \overline{\eta})$ equals the Galois group
  of maximal unramified extension of $k(\eta)$; see p. 41.
- it seems that the author suggests that one can use here
  the equivalence of categories between locally constant sheaves
  and finite $\pi_1(X, \overline{x})$-sets given by
  $\mathcal{F} \mapsto \mathcal{F}_{\overline{x}}$,
  respectively $M \mapsto \mathcal{F}(U)= \operatorname{Hom}_{\pi_1}
  (\operatorname{Hom}_X(\overline{x}, U),M) $.

The implication that for $\mathcal{F}$ locally
constant the $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{k(\eta)}/
k(\eta))$-action on $\mathcal{F}_{\overline{\eta}}$
factors through $\pi_1(X, \overline{\eta})$ is standard,
e.g., ([tag/0DV4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0DV4)).
Essentially, that's the equivalence above & independence
of geometric(= base) point.

But I not understand how the part with the
unit map
$\mathcal{F} \to g_*g^*\mathcal{F}$ fits in the picture.
Especially, why local constancy of $\mathcal{F}$ implies
the unit map is an isomorphism and respectively why it's
reversely necessary alongside the assumption on $\mathcal{F}_{\overline{\eta}}$. In light of a result [discussed here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452621/calculate-stalk-of-etale-derived-pushforward-sheaf-milnes-lec) which appears to be maybe useful here, the main problem with the calculation of the stalks of $g_*g^*\mathcal{F}$ is how to control $g^*\mathcal{F}$. In general it's even not locally constant again. What do we know about it in this context which might help here to establish this characterization of locally constant sheaves?
Can this problem be reduced to case $\mathcal{F}$ via descent techniques, ie after passing to an etale trivialization $U_i \to X$ of  $\mathcal{F}$ to deal with $\mathcal{F} \vert _{U_i} \to g_*g^*\mathcal{F}  \vert _{U_i}$ simplifying(?) the situation? But then what is the term on the rhside?

**#UPDATE\progress:** About that the unit $\mathcal{F} \to g_*g^*\mathcal{F}$ is an iso assuming $\mathcal{F}$ is locally constant.
Keeping in mind the philosophy @Balazs suggest that the involved locally constant sheaves are "rigid" enough that the "whole information" is concentrated more less in a single stalk (...please correct me if I misunderstood your point) - the stalk & the action datum - and it suffice to reconstruct the whole sheaf, it seems reasonable to me that we need only to show two things:

(1) That the unit map is an isomorphism in the stalk at generic point; still not know how to manage it. Maybe that's exactly the point where the normality assumption is going to be exploited.

**UPDATE #2**(on point (1)) I think one part where normality of $X$ is exploited is to show that the stalk of $g_*g^*\mathcal{F}$  and $\mathcal{F}$ at geometric points coinside abstractly, compare again with [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452621/calculate-stalk-of-etale-derived-pushforward-sheaf-milnes-lec) already linked above. But nevertheless, at this stage it's a priori not clear me why this should neccessarily imply that the unit map have to be an iso, or not?

(2) That $g_*g^*\mathcal{F}$ is locally constant;  a pullback of a locally constant sheaf retain this property, and to same is true for pushforward assuming it is performed along an etale map, but $g$ is *not* etale as noticed in the comments below.
How else one can firsly deduce that  $g_*g^*\mathcal{F}$  is locally constant (motivation: in order to simplify to check
that the unit map is iso it suffice to sheck it on a single stalk (+ action compatibility) - the generic point is the plausible candidate - assuming(!) we already know that both unvolved sheaves are locally constant...

Comment: I suppose that $f=g$?

Comment: @TomGoodwillie: Yes sure, thanks!

Comment: I am not an expert on the etale side of things, but I think this condition is trying to capture the notion that ''nothing extra happens at closed points'': topological behaviour is controlled by what is happening on the general fibre. You may wish to look at the notes http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~conrad/Weil2seminar/Notes/L3.pdf. Theorem 4.1 here gives you a condition for a etale sheaf to be locally constant in terms of specialisation maps being bijective, which I believe is equivalent to the more concise condition in terms of the unit map.

Comment: @Balazs: so far I understand the philosophy you suggesting correctly, the idea on the the establishing that the unit is an iso "indirectly", is based on showing two things: **Firstly,** that it is an iso in the generic point, and **secondly**, that  $g_*g^*\mathcal{F}  $ is locally constant. (the idea is so far I understand the philosophy correctly is that for locally constant essentially the whole story is told at only one stalk + action data; it seems natural to to work with stalk at generic point.

Comment: The second point is clear, because $g_*g^*\mathcal{F}$ is locally constant: pullback of locally const is loc const and pushforward along etale map - $g$ is etale so far I see - of loc const is loc const too. The missing part is that the unit map is iso at the stalk of generic point. I think it's managerable to show that the stalk of $g_*g^*\mathcal{F}$ at $\eta$ is abstractly isomorphic to the stalk of $\mathcal{F}$. But how to see that the stalk map *comming from the unit map* is an iso?

Comment: @user267839: $g$ is definitely not etale...

Comment: @Satan'sMinion: etale means flat & unramified. $g: \eta \to X$ is the inclusion of *generic* point. Why is it not etale precisely? It's clearly flat (since "morally" on level of rings/ sections it's nothing but the embedding of of coordinate ring into function field, so a localization), and on level of Zariski stalk in $\eta$ the stalk is identity, to in sense of [definition of unramified(https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unramified_morphism), $g$ is unramified too, or do I oversee something? Could you point out the error in my reasonings?

Comment: Indeed, therer seems something fishy with etaleness of $g$, but going through the characterization of it as flat & unramified I honestly cannot detect a gap in my considerations in comment above, do you see it?

Comment: @user267839  “Etale”, according to standard usage, includes “locally finitely presented” as one of the requirements.  What you call “etale” is closer to “formally etale.”

Comment: oh yes thanks, I see, so the my presented "argument" above that $g_*g^*\mathcal{F}$ is locally constant ( especially that pushforward along $g$ preserves loc const property since it assumes the standard notion so far I know) fails. Do you see how to argue correctly on that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) $ \mathcal F \to g_* g^* \mathcal F$ is an injection on the generic point.

Proof: In other words, the map $g^* \mathcal F \to g^* g_* g^* \mathcal F$ arising from the unit is an isomorphism. By a basic property of adjunctions, composing this with the map $g^* g_* g^* \mathcal F \to g^* \mathcal F$ coming from the counit gives the identity, so this map must be injective on stalks and the counit must be surjective on stalks so that their composition can be isomorphic on stalks.

(2) Let $\mathcal F$ be locally constant - in particular assume it is locally the constant sheaf associated to the set $\Lambda$. Then $g_* g^* \mathcal F$ is locally the constant sheaf associated to the set $\Lambda$.

Proof: Both $g_* $ and $g^*$ are local constructions so we may work étale-locally, and thus we may assume $\mathcal F$ is actually isomorphic to $\Lambda$. (Here we use that every étale open set in a normal variety is again normal.) Thus $g^* \mathcal F$ is $\Lambda$. So we must check that $g_* \Lambda$ is isomorphic to $\Lambda$. Recall that $\Lambda$ is the sheaf that sends an open set $U$ to the group $\Lambda$ raised to the set of connected components of $U$. There is a natural map $\Lambda \to g_* \Lambda$ arising from the natural map from the set of connnected components of $g^{-1}(U)$ to the set of connected components of $U$. This map is an isomorphism since $X$ is normal: $g^{-1}(U)$ is just the set of generic points of components of $U$ and each component has exactly one generic point.

Now if $\mathcal F$ is locally constant with finite stalks, this immediately implies $\mathcal F \to g_* g^* \mathcal F$ is an isomorphism, since at the generic point it's a map $\Lambda \to \Lambda$ which is injective and hence surjective, and then as you note since it's an map of locally constant sheaves which is an isomorphism at one point it's an isomorphism everywhere. If you want this for infinite sheaves it should be possible to do this by writing them as a limit of finite sheaves but I'm not sure if it's easier to make the limit play nice with the adjunction than to do this a different way.

This gives the "only if" direction (combined with what you already noted). For if, just note that if the Galois action on the stalk of $\mathcal F$ at $\eta$ factors through the étale fundamental group then $g^* \mathcal F$ is isomorphic to $g^* \mathcal L$ where $L$ is the locally constant sheaf corresponding to that representation of the étale fundamental group. So $\mathcal F \cong g_* g^* \mathcal F \cong g_* g^* \mathcal L$ is locally constant by the above.

Comment: In (1) you used that the counit $g^*g_* \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}$ is an iso. Do I understand it correctly that in etale world this holds for all immersions? Also, do you know a "standard way" how to see it? I'm (almost) familar with one eg from 
[Sheaves in Geometry and Logic](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0927-0), p 368 where is presented an argument strictly speaking on level of topological spaces, but it should be easy to mimic it nearly literally to obtain a proof for etale topos, up to one thing which I not fully understood:

Comment: The proof there showed only that the stalks of $g^*g_*F$ and $F$ at any point $y$ coincide, but strictly speaking the question is about if the *counit map* is an iso. Do I understand this crucial point here correctly that this argument from the quoted book (showing only that the stalks are isomorphic; compare also with 
[this problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462458/a-stalk-criterion-for-unit-map-to-be-an-isomorphism-on-%c3%a9tale-site) where I tried to eloborate this problem) is only "legal" here because of

Comment: the explicit construction of the counit map as more or less a "simultaneous" restriction map? More concretely, going through the explicit construction of counit, firstly it is declared explicitly on level of $f^{\dagger}f_* F \to F$
 (where $f^{\dagger}G$ is the usual inverse image presheaf) mapping naturally 
a section $s \in F(f^{-1}(V) \subset f^{\dagger}f_xF(U)$ (for $U \subset f^{-1}(V) $) to $\text{res}^{f^{-1}(V)}_U(s)$; ie beeing given "intuitively" more less as the "simultaneous" restriction map,

Comment: and then extending it to $g^*g_* F$ using that the latter is the sheafification of $f^{\dagger}f_* F$. And then - but *only* because of the observation in last sentence & invariance of stalks under sheafification -
the question just becomes if these $f^{-1}(V)$ for with $f(x) =y \in V$ become cofinal 
in the inductive system of etale neighborhoods of $x$, and this is answered just by showing that the stalks are isomorphic, that's the trick right?

Comment: And - if what I wrote so far is correct - this argument is based on really a special feature of counit map, which cannot mimicked for unit map, **exactly** due to the reason - so far I understood your explanation
correctly in 5th comment under [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/461822) - that in contrast to the issue for counit that $g^*g_* F$ beeing sheafification 
of $f^{\dagger}f_* F$, the $f_*f^* G$ is *not* sheafification of $f_* f^{\dagger}G$, and that's the crucial difference where the argument cannot be "dualized", right?

Comment: By the way, do you maybe know if there a less tedious argument to show that for an immersion the counit is an iso?

Comment: @user267839 No, I do not use that the counit is an iso in the arguments I give. A composition of two maps is injective only if the first map is injective, regardless of the second map. In this argument, the counit being an iso implies the unit is an iso on stalks, but the unit being injective is enough for the case of finite stalks. Your point about the argument not being dualizable makes sense, although I would have to think through examples to understand to what extent it can be made to work in special cases.

Comment: @user267839 I don't know of a less tedious argument. I think the main thing is, through practice, to get comfortable enough with arguments of this type that you can get through them quickly enough that they don't seem tedious, or that you can skip steps with confidence the overall statement is still correct.

Comment: right, sorry I misred your argument. Then so far I understand your argument for point (1) strictily speaking to obtain the iso on stalk at $\overline{\eta}$ on should pullback the whole constellation (ie the pullbacked by g unit, the counit and their composition, which is by construction the identity map) once more by canonical map to sep'ble closure $i_{\eta, \overline{\eta}}: \overline{\eta} \to \eta$ and make the elementary observation that $i_{\eta, \overline{\eta}} \circ g = i_{X, \overline{\eta}}: \overline{\eta} \to X$, which is exactly in geometric point of which the generic stalk is

Comment: is taken in (1). But of course by functoriality the argument goes trough, and this is just the technicality; the geometric picture is clear so far.

Comment: But I have another question about point (2): When you say that "since $g_* $ and $g^*$ are local constructions so we may work étale-locally" do you - technically speaking - invoke implicitly "smooth base change result"? Finally, what we want, is to show that $g_*g^* F$ is locally const; equivalently that there exist an etale cover $( U_i \to X)_i$ such that over each $U_i$ the considered sheaf is constant. Now when you invoke "locality" of  $g_* $ and $g^*$ do you in precise technical terms refer to that for $e: U \to X$ etale we have for a sheaf $G$ on $\eta$ $e^* g_* G \cong (g')_* (e')^* G$

Comment: for $g'$ (resp $e'$) pullback of $g$ (resp $e$) along $e$ resp $g$, right? (and even a honest identification for pullback of $g$ for trivial reasons by construction of pullback ). Is that precisely what you mean by "locality" described rigorously? (Consequently, the natural candidate for the trivializing cover of $f_*f^* F$ would of course be the the trivializing cover of $F$)

Comment: @user267839 Yes, it's exactly that kind of base change formula. The only thing is I claim the étale case is easier to prove than the general smooth case and follows from unraveling the definitions. (The key point is that pullback by an étale morphism admits a simpler formula with no limit and no sheafification.)